# Не получается передать несколько моделей в post

Tags: api, asp.net-core

в api есть метод:

```
    [Route("Product/Create")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(Products product, Group group)
    {

    }
```

`Products` и `Group` - модели. Как в данном случае будет выглядеть post запрос к api??? Либо может как то по другому организовать код?

Так же не могу использовать атрибут `[FromUri]`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пост запрос подразумевает передачу данных в body запроса. Если тебе нужно передать именно две модели сразу, то объединяй их в одну более крупную.

Comment: @adrug  а [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/2.6.php) написано что так можно

Comment: Так у вас не aspnet mvc, а aspnetcore.
Почитайте [мануалы по привязкам](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @adrug т е мне нужно создать класс-модель включающую поля из двух сущностей, и потом когда приму ее в посте использовать уже для каждой сущности отдельно? я все правильно понял?

Comment: Это самый простой способ, но вы меня неправильно. Поместите свои 2 сущности в другую.

Comment: @adrug а если вместо объектов передавать ихние поля в post, а потом с помощью запроса sql обращаться к разным таблицам. Мне кажется так проще будет